# Sencha Touch 2.0 and navigation.View - MVC

Tags: touch, extjs

I would like to switch views with a button, there is absolutely no examples of it in a MVC context in the sencha documentation although they recommend developers to use their build in MVC architecture. I guess its because Touch 2.0 is rather new.

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api

The video about the list component is also about navigation.View, but since the list component is used, they dont show how to switch views with a button.

Video: [Intro to List Component](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/video/list)

This is the code i have so far:

uddannelser.js (First view)

```
Ext.define("VUCFyn.view.uddannelser", {
extend: "Ext.navigation.View",
xtype: "uddannelser",
requires: [
    "VUCFyn.view.avu"
],

config: {
    title: "Uddannelser",
    cls: "uddannelser",
    items: [
        {
            title: "Uddannelser",
            xtype: "container",
            margin: 20,
            layout: "vbox",
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: "button",
                    text: "AVU",
                    width: 100
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}});
```

avu.js (subview of uddannelser)

```
Ext.define("VUCFyn.view.avu", {
extend: "Ext.Panel",
xtype: "avu",

config: {
    title: "AVU",
    cls: "avu",
    scrollable: true,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: "label",
            html: [
                "<p>Almen Voksenuddannelse - avu - er et tilbud om uddannelse til alle over 18 år. Du kan tage avu-fagene et ad gangen eller i en kombination med flere fag. Du kan også kombinere avu-fagene med andre enkeltfag på FVU og/eller hf.</p>",
                "<h5>AVU omfatter kernefagene:</h5>",
            ].join("")
        }
    ]
}});
```

Main.js (controller)

```
Ext.define('VUCFyn.controller.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

config: {
    refs: {
        uddannelser: "uddannelser"
    },
    control: {
        "uddannelser": {
            tap: "showDetail"
        }
    }
},

showDetail: function () {
    this.getUddannelser().push({
        xtype: "avu"
    });
},

init: function () {

}});
```

Please, if someone could show me how to do it, based on the above code (or similar) that would be great.

btw: the answers in this thread: [Sencha Touch 2 MVC - how to switch views with button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883097/sencha-touch-2-mvc-how-to-switch-views-with-button) is not working for me. (No errors though) I think its for Sencha Touch 1.1, and a lot of things have apparently changed in 2.0

Comment: Check out this simple NavigationView example from Sencha Docs .. http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/navigation_view (though not in MVC format, this is what you might want)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you just need to fix the controller and it will work, try the following and let me know how you get on.

```
config: {
refs: {
    uddannelser: "uddannelser",
    uddannelserButton: "uddanelser button"
},
control: {
    "uddannelserButton": {
        tap: "showDetail"
    }
}
```

},

So all I have done is add a selector for the button in your uddanelser view and attached the click listener to that. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to listen for tap events on the `navigationview` you've given the uddannelser `cls`? There's a couple of issues with your setup;

Firstly, it doesn't look like you are using component queries properly in your controller, check this documentation: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery

Depending on how many of these components in the view you want the controller to manage, you can either give it an id and search for the component by `"#id"` or you can use the `xtype` and a config option, such as `"navigationview[cls=uddannelser]"`.

Secondly, you can't listen for tap events on a `navigationview`, if you wanted to listen for tap events on this component you'd have to listen for the tap event on the `element` and relay the event. I suspect you are actually trying to listen for the tap event on the `button` though, in that case create two refs in your controller, one for the `navigationview` and one for the `button`, listen for the tap event on the `button` and push the panel on the `navigationview` like you are now.